# How do I generate error report emails in Classic ASP?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-10

I want to capture 500 errors in my classic ASP application and receive an email of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem I had was getting a page to execute at all when an asp page crashed. Either IIS let it through for ASP to handle the error (which is useless because `customErrors` tag is completely ignored) or it would take over and blank out `Server.GetLastError`.

In the end I figured out that if you set the `defaultPath` directly to `httpErrors` and have the `defaultResponseMode` to `ExecuteURL` it will not only execute the actual 500.asp page but it will let the page be so that `Server.GetLastError` can remain populated.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>    
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors defaultPath="/500.asp" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

500.asp

```
<%option explicit%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%  
    'Get Error
    Dim objASPError
    Set objASPError = Server.GetLastError

    'Reset Response
    If Response.Buffer Then
        Response.Clear
        Response.Status = "500 Internal Server Error"
        Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        Response.Expires = 0
    End If

    'CSS
    dim style : style = "<style type='text/css'>"
    style = style & "table { width: 800px; } "  
    style = style & "#debugInfo th{ text-align:left; background-color:palegoldenrod; }"
    style = style & "#debugInfo td{ background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow; }"
    style = style & "#sessionInfo th{ text-align:left; background-color:cyan;}"
    style = style & "#sessionInfo td{ background-color:lightcyan; }"
    style = style & "#appInfo th{ text-align:left; background-color:tomato; }"
    style = style & "#appInfo td{ background-color:pink; }"
    style = style & "</style>"

    ' Error Message
    Dim errMsg : errMsg = ""    
    errMsg = errMsg &"<p>"
    errMsg = errMsg & objASPError.Category & "(0x" & hex(objASPError.Number) & ")<br />"
    errMsg = errMsg & objASPError.Description & "<br />"
    errMsg = errMsg & objASPError.File & ", line " & objASPError.Line & "<br />"
    errMsg = errMsg & objASPError.Source & "<br />"
    errMsg = errMsg & "</p>"

    'Debug Info
    Dim debugInfo : debugInfo = ""
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<table id='debugInfo'>"    
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<tr> <th colspan='2' style='text-align:center;background-color:gold;padding:2px;'>Debug Information</th> </tr>"    
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<tr> <th>User</th>     <td>"& Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER") &"</td> </tr>"
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<tr> <th>Time</th>     <td>"& Now() &"</td> </tr>"     
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<tr> <th>Page</th>     <td>"& Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") &"</td> </tr>"
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<tr> <th>User IP</th>  <td>"& Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST") & " (" & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") &")</td> </tr>"
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<tr> <th>Browser</th>  <td>"& Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT") &"</td> </tr>"
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<tr> <th>Server</th>   <td>"& Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & " (" & Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR") &")</td> </tr>"    
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "<tr> <th>POST</th>     <td>"& Request.Form &"</td> </tr>"
    debugInfo = debugInfo & "</table>"  

    'Session Variables
    Dim sessionVar, sessionVarItem, sessionTable
    sessionTable = "<table id='sessionInfo'>"   
    sessionTable = sessionTable & "<tr><th colspan='2' style='text-align:center;background-color:dodgerblue;padding:2px;'>Session Variables ("& Session.Contents.Count  &")</th></tr>"  
    For Each sessionVar in Session.Contents
        If IsArray(Session(sessionVar)) Then
            For appVarItem = LBound(Session(sessionVar)) to UBound(Session(sessionVar))
                sessionTable = sessionTable & "<tr>"
                sessionTable = sessionTable & "<th>" & sessionVar & " " & sessionVarItem & "</th>"
                sessionTable = sessionTable & "<td>" & Session(sessionVar)(sessionVarItem) & "</td>"
                sessionTable = sessionTable & "</tr>"
            Next
        Else
            sessionTable = sessionTable & "<tr>"
            sessionTable = sessionTable & "<th>" & sessionVar & "</th>"
            sessionTable = sessionTable & "<td>" & Session(sessionVar) & "</td>"
            sessionTable = sessionTable & "</tr>"
        End If
    Next
    sessionTable = sessionTable & "</table>"

    'Application Variables
    Dim appVar, appVarItem, appVarTable
    appVarTable = "<table id='appInfo'>"    
    appVarTable = appVarTable & "<tr><th colspan='2' style='text-align:center;background-color:lightcoral;padding:2px;'>Application Variables ("& Application.Contents.Count  &")</th></tr>"    
    For Each appVar in Application.Contents
        If IsArray(Application(appVar)) Then
            For appVarItem = LBound(Application(appVar)) to UBound(Application(appVar))
                appVarTable = appVarTable & "<tr>"
                appVarTable = appVarTable & "<th>" & appVar & " " & appVarItem & "</th>"
                appVarTable = appVarTable & "<td>" & Application(item)(appVarItem) & "</td>"
                appVarTable = appVarTable & "</tr>"
            Next
        Else
            appVarTable = appVarTable & "<tr>"
            appVarTable = appVarTable & "<th>" & appVar & "</th>"
            appVarTable = appVarTable & "<td>" & Application(appVar) & "</td>"
            appVarTable = appVarTable & "</tr>"
        End If
    Next
    appVarTable = appVarTable & "</table>"


    'Send Email
    dim tech : tech = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName = "ITGuy"
    If NOT tech Then
        Dim oMessage : Set oMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
        oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")      = 2
        oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")     = "smtp.server.com"
        oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

        oMessage.To = "ITGuy@server.com"
        oMessage.From = "WebApp@server.com"
        oMessage.Subject="WebApp Error - " & objASPError.Category
        oMessage.htmlBody = style & errMsg & debugInfo & sessionTable & appVarTable
        oMessage.Send
    End If
%>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>System Error</title>
        <% If tech Then Response.Write style%>
    </head>
    <body>
        Sorry! The system encountered an error. An email has been sent to IT. If you have any concerns or questions please send an email to <a href="mailto:ITGuy@server.com">ITGuy@server.com</a> or call x555.
        <%If tech Then Response.Write errMsg & debugInfo & sessionTable & appVarTable %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @martha ! I was so concerned about posting something sensitive on the GitHub I made for this that I completely overlooked checking the code here. :(